# unable to locate "msoftcon.h" in includePath with MSYS2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, msys2

I am try to implement some console-based graphics program with **"msoftcon.h"** graphics library. I have installed **MSYS2** to work with C/C++ development. However when I am trying to include this header file. I am getting error:

```
#include "msoftcon.h"
---------------------
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (D:\Programming\C C++\C++\Pointers\horse.cpp).C/C++(1696)
```

I have **(g++ v13.^)** and I am running it on a **windows** system with **VScode**.
Can someone provide me with the steps to put this header file (if needed to be install externally) or is it deprecated and I have to work with some other alternative ? As there is no updated source I was able find about this header file.

Comment: `msoftcon.h` is not a standard header for C++ or MS-Windows.  Have you downloaded the _"unknown"_ graphics library you want to use?

Comment: @Richard Critten, No. So from where I have to download this header file and how I have to include this header file ? In the bin/ of MSYS2 or I have to include this in my project dir?

Comment: I have no idea.  Perhaps ask the source that recommended you this header file / library.

Comment: Some very cursory searching indicates that it's some ancient header that's not part of any library. I've seen versions of the header included in other projects, and I've seen it mentioned in the breath as borlacon.h. It includes some Windows headers itseslf, but it doesn't look to be from Microsoft.

Comment: ***In the bin/ of MSYS2*** You should not put it in the bin folder. You can put it in the `C:\msys64\mingw64\include` folder but I am not sure you should pollute the msys2 install with external headers. You may just want to put it in your application's folder.

Comment: @sweenish, If this is an older header file for console graphics. So, Is there any good alternatives which Is in MSYS2 list?

Comment: ***console graphics*** Do you have a link to this? Is it just ascii or actual graphical?

Comment: ***Please update your includePath.*** Means to edit you `c_cpp_properties.json` although remember the changes you make in that file are just for the Intellisense and not compiling at all. To add an include path for compiling you edit your `tasks.json` The official documentation describes these 3 important json files here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: One thing is, it doesn't have to be provided by MSYS2. You'll want to look into build systems like cmake, and possibly package managers like Conan/vcpkg. C++ provides zero tooling, so you have to put this stuff together in a way that works for you. Plain ncurses might be sufficient, maybe something like FTXUI. Maybe SDL, Qt (more of a complete ecosystem on its own), etc. It becomes very easy to see why SO isn't a recommendations site.

Comment: @drescherjm, I am trying to draw shapes like a rectangle, circle etc.